# Single Object JSON Array?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, json, xml

I'm Using My Employee table Like this,

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| Empid | Empname | Salary | Location |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
|     1 | Arul    |    100 | Chennai  |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

XML Generate SQl Query:

```
select * from employee for xml path, root('root')
```

from this Sql Query I'm Getting My XML Files as given below

```
<root>
  <employee>
    <Empid>1</Empid>
    <Empname>Arul</Empname>
    <Salary>100</Salary>
    <Location>Chennai</Location>
  </employee>
</root>
```

But My Expected Output XML from SQL query as

```
<root>
<column>Empid</column>
<value>1</value>
<column>Empname</column>
<value>Arul</value>
</root>
```

Comment: Where does JSON come into play?

Comment: Here This Format of XML Needs to come into The Single Object Array.          
    {
  "column": [
    "Empid",
    "Empname"
  ],
  "value": [
    "1",
    "Arul"
  ]
}

Comment: There is not inbuilt query or way available in C# or SQL to get the JSON you want. You need to get the data and column information from database to the C# and generate your own class to represent the JSON structure and populate it and serialize it to JSON. Did you try any such things?

Comment: In Before going to generate JSON ,I Need a XML File In This Mentioned Format from SQL query,                                                                                                   <root>
<column>Empid</column>
<value>1</value>
<column>Empname</column>
<value>Arul</value>
</root>